# openapi yaml file having callback not generating the callback code

Tags: java, spring, swagger, openapi, swagger-codegen

I am trying to generate API & Model classes (java files) from OpenAPI (3.0.x) yaml file through swagger code generator (Server side). I am using suggestions from the swagger official website below:

https://swagger.io/docs/specification/callbacks/

First time I generated spring java classes (API & Models) without callback and then I generated the java classes with callback. But both are giving me same API and Model java files. Nowhere I am seeing any extra lines of code generated for adding callback in the yaml file. Please help.

**Without callback :**

```
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  version: 0.0.0
  title: test
paths:
  /subscribe:
    post:
      summary: Subscribe to a webhook
      requestBody:
        required: true
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              type: object
              properties:
                callbackUrl:   # Callback URL
                  type: string
                  format: uri
                  example: https://myserver.com/send/callback/here
              required:
                - callbackUrl
      responses:
        '201':
          description: Webhook created
```

**With Callback :**

```
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  version: 0.0.0
  title: test
paths:
  /subscribe:
    post:
      summary: Subscribe to a webhook
      requestBody:
        required: true
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              type: object
              properties:
                callbackUrl:   # Callback URL
                  type: string
                  format: uri
                  example: https://myserver.com/send/callback/here
              required:
                - callbackUrl
      responses:
        '201':
          description: Webhook created
      callbacks:   # Callback definition
        myEvent:   # Event name
          '{$request.body#/callbackUrl}':   # The callback URL,
                                            # Refers to the passed URL
            post:
              requestBody:   # Contents of the callback message
                required: true
                content:
                  application/json:
                    schema:
                      type: object
                      properties:
                        message:
                          type: string
                          example: Some event happened
                      required:
                        - message
              responses:   # Expected responses to the callback message
                '200':
                  description: Your server returns this code if it accepts the callback
```

Comment: I'm not sure Swagger Codegen supports callback generation. See if there's an existing issue in https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues or create a new one.

Comment: Okay. But they have mentioned one example regarding callback in yaml file in the official website. So I thought it will generate the callback as callback configuration is mentioned in yaml file.
https://swagger.io/docs/specification/callbacks/